# When was a feature branch opened, without checking out the whole repo?

Tags: git

I would like to read out the date, when a feature branch was opened, but don't want to checkout the whole repository.

In my "normal-cloned-repo" I can do a `git log develop..feature/long-living-feature --oneline --reverse` and see the first commit of the feature branch. (In fact, it is the first commit, after the feature branch has been merged back into develop, but I am okay with that. If I could also improve that, it would be nice, too. It would be nicer to find the commit from which the feature branch was created initially.)

Since I am writing a small application, which should generate a report, I don't want to clone a lot of repositories fully for that need. Because also the info of the last commit is required, I cloned the repo without files like that: `git clone <url> <path> --filter=blob:none --no-checkout --single-branch --branch feature/long-living-feature`.

Executing my above command in this repository throws the following error:

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'develop..feature/long-living-feature':
> unknown revision or path not in the working tree. Use '--' to separate
> paths from revisions, like this: 'git  [...] --
> [...]'

Looks like this repo is missing the references to develop, may be?

How can I read the date without checking out the full repository?

Comment: What does the word "opened" mean here? I might "open a branch" by doing `git checkout` on it, for instance, to extract the files from its tip commit. Or I might "open a (new) branch" by creating the *name*. I suspect you're asking about the latter. There's a problem with finding either one though: Git simply does not record this information. (Your own answer is probably the best you can do.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I have found an answer:

First, get the last commit hashes of all branches:

```
git ls-remote --heads <url>
```

Then clone the repository with minimal size:

```
git clone <path> <url> --filter=tree:0 --no-checkout
```

Finally, use [git merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base)-base to find the best common ancestor between two commits.

```
git merge-base <developHash> <branchHash>
```

And of course, e.g. a `git show <hash> --format="%cD"` will give us the date.

So, this will still not give us the commit from which the branch was created, but it is good enough for me. Any hints, how that commit can be found with basic git commands, are of course still very welcome.